# Problem starting Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, grub2, data-recovery, busybox

I have an Acer Aspire 7730 laptop (Acer Aspire 7730). After a power failure it shows me only the GNU GRUB menu with these options:

- Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0.24 - generic
- Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0.24 - generic (safe mode)
- Memory test (memtest86+)
- Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)

If I choose either of the the first options it starts the busybox menu. Can I fix this from this console or must I use a live CD (which at the moment I don't have)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's dropping you to busybox, using a Live CD/USB is the faster and more practical option.

You generally get dropped to busybox when grub cannot find the files on `/boot` -- or the `/boot` partition itself. The power failure may have affected your filesystem or the partition table, so you're best off with the Live CD rather than risk messing anything up from within busybox.

Comment: Thanks, I already solved my problem, using a liveCD and fsck -l /dev/sda1, after an restart everything went normally

Comment: Happy to help, glad everything worked out!